# error while appending data into an array using array_push in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to filter my `data_array` and create a new array `$arr` with new data.I tried using following function.it is not appending data. but it is replacing the data.I know that I have to use `array_push()`. when I did that data is appending to the  array as **single** **elements**.

```
 foreach ($data_array as $value) {

                try {
                    $rep = $value->rep;
                    $idposition_rep = $value->idposition_rep;
                    $max_idinvoice = $value->max_idinvoice;
                    $idsession = $value->idsession;
                    $i_date = $value->i_date;
                    $last_i_time_string = $value->last_i_time;
                    $delayTime = $value->delayTime;
                    if ($delayTime > 30) {
                        $arr[] = array(
                            'rep' => $rep,
                            'idposition_rep' => $idposition_rep,
                            'max_idinvoice' => $max_idinvoice,
                            'idsession' => $idsession,
                            'i_date' => $i_date,
                            'last_i_time_string' => $last_i_time_string,
                            'curr_time' => date("H:i:s"),
                            'delayTime' => $delayTime);
                    }
                } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    echo $ex->getMessage();
                    die;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You want to do what? What's the error?

Comment: I want to send  the $arr to the model but only one data set is sending.

Comment: from $data_array i want a new array $arr where $delayTime>30.please  just help me to do that.

Comment: have you define $arr before the foreach loop ? $arr = Array();

Comment: can wee see an extract of $data_array ?

Comment: Where is `array_push()`?

Comment: it would be nice to actually see the output you are getting.  also where you are initializing $arr and where you print the output

Answer (score 0):

I had created sample code based on your requirement. replace as per your requirement with variables and assignment.
$data_array is sample input array.

$data_array = array('1' => 'abc', '2'=>'das', '3' => 'def');

$arr = array(); 
$i=0;

> ```
> foreach ($data_array as $value)  {
>
> try {
>     $rep = $value;
>     $aval = strpos($rep,'a');  // Put Your condition for display Time > 30
>     if ($aval !== false) {
>     $arr[$i] = array(
>         'rep' => $rep // assign values get from input array.
>       );
>     $i++;
>     }
> } catch (PDOException $ex) {
>     echo $ex->getMessage();
>     die;
> } }
> ```

print_r($arr);

**OUTPUT:**

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rep] => abc
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [rep] => das
        )
)

Hope this will help you.